# Get a User Information in Github using PyGithub

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygithub

I am new to Github programming. I'd like to get user details who are in github by giving the username as input. How do I do that using pygithub?

Also how do I get their profile photo too?

Thank you

Comment: You can learn the module [here](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: specifically https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/AuthenticatedUser.html

Comment: Thank you.. I give the command  >>>a=github.Github()
>>> a.get_user("https://github.com/xxxxx")  It shows the error  
" raise self.__createException(status, responseHeaders, output)
github.GithubException.UnknownObjectException: 404 {u'documentation_url': u'https://developer.github.com/v3', u'message': u'Not Found'}"  What to do..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.github.com/en/articles/searching-users

This link has the syntax for searching users information

```
Import github
g=github.Github()
users=g.search_users(str(username)+" in:login")
```

You can refer the formate and use it in python like this 
This search_users function returns all the information about the user which are available in public.